# Searching for text in questions I have answered

Tags: feature-request, search

The question [pendulum modeling](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2272496/pendulum-modeling) is essentially a duplicate of the question [mathematical model of a pendulum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2270885/mathematical-model-of-a-pendulum).  I had supplied an answer to the older one and wanted to find it.  I searched on my user number plus pendulum ([`user:1827 pendulum`](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A1827+pendulum)), but it did not find my answer.  I suspect it was because I did not use the word pendulum in my answer, it was only in the question.

The search function needs to be broader about where it looks for the terms searched for.

Comment: Yeah, for a long time I felt like this is a missing feature...

Comment: Related post on the main meta: [Searching for term in question, but with an answer by a given user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286048). (It is tagged as support, not feature-request. The accepted answer suggests to use a [SEDE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info) query.)

Comment: However, as data in SEDE are only updated once a week, it does not help [to find this specific question](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/560120/questions-answered-by-a-user-containing-text?UserId=1827&Text=pendulum). (At least at the moment.)

Comment: I use [user:1827 pendulum site:math.stackexchange.com](https://www.google.de/search?q=user%3A1827+pendulum+site%3Amath.stackexchange.com&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=BssRWffNCfTJXrzfv4AF) in such cases...

Comment: I have been keeping a text file at home. There are a few dozen topics where I have made multiple answers or otherwise think I would like to be able to find things later; usually my own answers, not always. I guess the point is that I get to organize the list as I find useful. There are plenty of one-off answers i will never find again.

Comment: @draks... Did you perhaps mean something like ["Ross Millikan" pendulum site:math.stackexchange.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Ross+Millikan%22+pendulum+site:math.stackexchange.com)? I mean username rather than user id. The syntax [user:userid](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A1827+pendulum) or [user:me](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame+pendulum) works in the built-in-search, but it only returns the posts where the keyword was used. (So not the situation described by the OP.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak true, but isn't the username just one click away...?

Comment: @draks... If you have a look at the actual search results, the search you linked did not find any questions. The search from my comment (with username rather than userid) returns several results, including the question the OP mentioned. (Although since Google indexes meta, too, the ranking of that particular question in the search results might have been increased because of being mentioned here on meta.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak hmm I thought I tried, but it looks like I didn't check the result. Sorry...